# Updating htaccess file with new contents gives errors

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to make a certain configuration to my apache in order to utilize a certain npm package https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server over cpanel. So I was wondering if it is possible to safely add the follow code to an existing `.htacess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:6001/$1 [P,L]

ProxyPass        /socket.io http://localhost:6001/socket.io
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://localhost:6001/socket.io
```

Here are the contents of the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

**EDIT:**

I do not have root access to place it within my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` as a virtualhost.

Comment: If you have access to the actual host configuration, then why would you want to use a distributed configuration file (".htaccess")? Those have clear disadvantages...

Comment: Thank you for responding. Can you please explain the disadvantages to me @arkascha

Comment: Distributed configuration files are only offered as a last means for those without access to the actual host configuration. They add complexity, are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and most important: the really slow down the http server...

Comment: Okay thank you @arkascha I'm running on a shared hosting and after consulting my host. They can't help me make such changes. As that's the case is there still a way I can go about this safely?

Comment: I am confused... Now do you have access to the actual host configuration as claimed in the question or do you _not_ have control over that?

Comment: I thought I did, but no. I have SSH access but not not root access.

Comment: @arkascha I have edited the question. And also resolved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem by placing this within my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^socket.io/? http://localhost:6001/socket.io [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Very good that you have shared with us what solve your problem, keep it up(learning and sharing). Just an additional note you could change(optional and could help you in future) `(www\.)?sub.domain\.com` to `^(?:www\.)sub.domain\.com` too where `?:` refers a non capturing group.